# Creating Custom Spinner Model

Tags: java, swing, abstract-class, jspinner

I'm trying to create a custom JSpinner that represents a sequence of numbers of power 2. Like, 1-2-4-8-16 and so on. I have to do that with extending AbstractSpinnerModel and changing its implemented methods (getNextValue etc.). The problem is, the arrow keys on my custom JSpinner don't work. Nothing changes when I click one of them. I need to show previous and next values of current value. ( Previous value = 4 Current Value = 8 Next Value = 16 ).

Here is my code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Hw5SpinnerModel extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hw5SpinnerModel frame = new Hw5SpinnerModel();

}

public Hw5SpinnerModel() {

    setTitle("Hw5SpinnerModel");
    setSize(350, 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JSpinner jspn = new JSpinner(new CustomSpinnerModel());

    final JLabel jlbl = new JLabel("");

    add(jspn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(jlbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jspn.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

            jlbl.setText(jspn.getPreviousValue() + jspn.getValue() + jspn.getNextValue());

        }

    });

    //jlbl.setText(jspn.getNextValue() + "");

    setVisible(true);

}

public class CustomSpinnerModel extends AbstractSpinnerModel {

    Integer i = 1;

    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        i = (Integer) value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNextValue() {
        return 2 * i;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPreviousValue() {
        return i / 2;
    }

}

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    jSpinner1.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, null, null, 1) {
        @Override
        public Object getNextValue() {                
            Object nextValue = super.getValue();
            int x = Integer.valueOf(nextValue.toString())*2;
            //Object o = x;
            return x;
        }
    });
```

It works 100%

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem this week, and here's the answer to your question: The JSpinner operates through the use of ChangeListeners, and those ChangeListeners need to be activated when the model's value changes.

You may have had difficulty finding this (as I did), because you thought that getNextValue and getPreviousValue, in your custom class, were returning bad values. They aren't; but the JSpinner just doesn't use them directly. It feeds them straight back to the SpinnerModel through setValue.

(Except if getNextValue or getPreviousValue return null, which is a special case. Then the JSpinner does nothing.)

So, in code, your setValue function needs a fireStateChanged call after the change to i:

```
@Override
public void setValue(Object value) {
    i = (Integer) value;
    fireStateChanged ();
}
```

You might think that the JSpinner shouldn't operate this way, and should take the value from getNextValue and getPreviousValue to display immediately, instead of this indirect process. But the JSpinner has to call setValue in any case, and setValue has to notify the ChangeListeners in any case (because a single model can be passed around to many places in your program).

For instance, if you had two JSpinners in different places, with the same SpinnerModel, then changes to the model need to be reflected on both JSpinners, but only one JSpinner gets to call getNextValue or getPreviousValue at one time.